# I always need to ifdown/ifup wlan0 after reboot

Tags: debian, networking, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create an ad-hoc wifi made of 5 computers (one Windows PC and 4 raspberry pi's loaded with a raspbian). The raspberry pi will talk through mqtt, but that's not the point. The problem I have is that I always need to do the following in order to have the `wlan0` interface after each reboot:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

Do you know why? Here is my conf (the same on each pi except the IP address obviously!)

```
~ % ifconfig                 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:ff:88:99  
          inet addr:192.168.1.41  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:951 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:266 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:66321 (64.7 KiB)  TX bytes:43663 (42.6 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:13:51:05:8c  
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:2520 (2.4 KiB)

~ % iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"mirroir"  
          Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Cell: 42:B1:44:EB:D2:C1   
          Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.


~ % more /etc/network/interfaces 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 1
    wireless-essid mirroir
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
    wireless-key 967136deac

~ % sudo route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 wlan0

~ % netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Any idea?

It seems to work, but not always -- like 1 boot out of 10, really weird?!

Comment: Is that the setting after the down/up or before?

Comment: after, before `wlan0` has no ip

Comment: i can't see how it is figuring out the gateway ip? maybe try adding `gateway 192.168.1.254` directly under the `netmask 255.255.255.0` line in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried one of the solutions below? I have to guess the answer here as the problem is not easy to reproduce, may be an issue with the driver you got.

1. In the interfaces file try commenting out "auto wlan0" and just keep "allow-hotplug wlan0"

   ```
   #auto wlan0
   allow-hotplug wlan0
   iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   ... rest of the config ...
   ```
2. Probably not the ideal solution you are looking for but try creating a new shell script with execute privileges in your favourite scripts directory with the following content.

   ```
   ifdown wlan0 
   ifup wlan0
   ```

   Then add the following line to your interfaces file.

   ```
   auto wlan0
   iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   ... rest of the config ...
   post-up /path-to-your-script/script.sh
   ```
3. When your computer starts up without the wireless connection active. Try fiddling with `iwconfig` with different parameters (try man iwconfig to get a complete list) until your interface comes up. I guess may be `txpower` sort of switch might help you out here. If that works for you, then use `pre-up <command-that-worked>` in your interfaces file like in the 2nd answer and leave the command there.

   So something like this at the end (remember to pass absolute paths to (pre|post)-up

   ```
   pre-up /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 txpower on
   ```

Comment: Hi, thx for that complete answer! I tried the first solution without success. The workaround i use is the solution 2, I added it in `/etc/rc.local`. I should give a try to the third solution you're giving. Thanks!

Comment: did any of the above solutions work for you? if you have managed to solve the problem please share.. thanks

Comment: hi, I haven't tried yet the third one, i will give a try next week

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Exactly same problem here. The problem was a timing issue: wlan0 wasn't ready when the boot process issued the `ifup`.

I solved this by adding a wait statement `pre-up sleep 5` to wlan0 in the interfaces file:

```
marcelo@breeze:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  pre-up sleep 5 
  address 10.0.0.42
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 10.0.0.2
  dns-nameservers 10.0.0.2
  wpa-ssid mycoolssid
  wpa-psk returnguantanamo
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use different "local" networks for the eth0 interfaces and wlan0.

So for wlan use network like `10.10.0.1`, mask `255.255.255.0`
And for eth use network like `192.168.0.1`, mask `255.255.255.0`

I haven't had this problem on RPI (probably because I always keep wlan0 and eth0 network IPs very different). But on my windows PC I have this problem all the time:
When I use wireless with `192.168.1.x` and then I plug into ethernet port, for example my rasbperry with `192.168.0.x` address (mind the 3rd octet), I always loose network connection.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment `auto eth0`, `auto eth1` or `auto wlan` for the interface you wish to come up when the unit boots.